# How to activate support for AsyncResponse (JAX-RS) on Wildlfy 11

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly-11

when i try a simple example for AsyncResponse

```
@Path("test")
public class AsyncTest {
   @GET
   public void test(@Suspended AsyncResponse res) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

i get the message

> UT010026: Async is not supported for this request, as not all filters
>   or Servlets were marked as supporting async

how can i get this working on wildfly 11

Thank you

Comment: Try annotating your method with `@Asynchronous`.

Comment: I found the problem: i used a filter and i had to activate the asyc-support: `<async-supported>true</async-supported>`

Thank you